# How to assign colors to boxplot in R? Can only use base R

Tags: r, plot, graph, colors, boxplot

I'm having trouble trying to assign colors to my boxplot in R. This is my code and output when I try to run the code. Really not sure what to do

````
region1<-c("North-Apulia","Calabria","South-Apulia","Sicily")
region2<-c("Inland-Sardinia,","Coast-Sardinia")
region3<-c("Umbria","East-Liguria","West-Liguria")
# c - Boxplots
mycolors<-ifelse(levels(betterolivelabel)==region1,col="red",
                 ifelse(levels(betterolivelabel)==region2,col="blue",
                        ifelse(levels(betterolivelabel)==region3, col="green")))```


```Error in ifelse(levels(betterolivelabel) == region1, col = "red", ifelse(levels(betterolivelabel) ==  : 
  unused argument (col = "red")```
>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to compare more than 1 value use `%in%`. Also you need to provide a final value when none of the conditions are satisfied.

```
lvls <- levels(betterolivelabel)

mycolors<-ifelse(lvls %in% region1,"red",
                 ifelse(lvls %in% region2,"blue",
                        ifelse(lvls %in% region3, "green", "black")))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
lvls <- levels(betterolivelabel)
mycolors <- case_when(lvls %in% region1 ~ "red",
                      lvls %in% region2 ~ "blue",
                      lvls %in% region3 ~ "green",
                      TRUE ~ "black")
```